# Is there a way to programmatically enable/disable captions to a Youtube video using their API?

Tags: youtube-api

I'd like to enable and disable specific captions tracks of my videos using Youtube's API. Is there any way to do this?

I've only found the way to update/delete a caption track but not how to enable/disable it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this using the current YouTube Data API. I'd recommend [filing a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Enhancement%20Request%29) if you'd like to see this added.